# How to use Gatsbys wrapPageElement with Typescript in a local plugin?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, gatsby

I'm trying to create a new Gatsby plugin. I started with developing it as [a local plugin](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/creating-a-local-plugin/). In this plugin I want to provide a `wrapPageElement` for server side rendering and during runtime, so I've create the following configuration files:

**gatsby-ssr.js**:

```
export { wrapPageElement } from "./src/wrapPageElement";
```

**gatsby-browser.js**:

```
export { wrapPageElement } from "./src/wrapPageElement";
```

**src/wrapPageElement.tsx**:

```
import React from "react";
import { GatsbyBrowser, GatsbySSR } from "gatsby";

type WrapPageElement =
  | GatsbyBrowser["wrapPageElement"]
  | GatsbySSR["wrapPageElement"];

export const wrapPageElement: WrapPageElement = ({ element, props }: any) => {
  return <div {...props}>{element}</div>;
};
```

Now when I run my Gatsby project I get the following runtime error:

```
One unhandled runtime error found in your files. See the list below to fix it:

Unknown Runtime Error

Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. Check the render method of `PageRenderer`.
:

No codeFrame could be generated
```

When I don't try to render `{element}` within the `wrapPageElement`, for example a simple string, the `wrapPageElement` is successfully rendered. The problem seems to be related to `element`. Does somebody have an idea what is wrong here?

I'm on Gatsby version `3.14.0`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was, that my page I tried to render didn't have a default export.

Instead of ..

```
import React from "react";

export default function IndexPage() {
  return <div>
    Index
  </div>
}
```

.. I defined ..

```
import React from "react";

export function IndexPage() {
  return <div>
    Index
  </div>
}
```

.. what caused the error.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be unresolved (yet) according to [this GitHub thread](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/26594), where apparently types are not properly exported by Gatsby.

As a hacky workaround you can try:

```
type Fn = (...args: Parameters<WrapPageElement>) => ReturnType<WrapPageElement>

export const wrapPageElement: Fn = ({ element, props }: any) => {
  return <div {...props}>{element}</div>;
};
```

*Note: modified from the source in the GitHub's thread*

Comment: Thank you for answering and pointing me to the existing issue. Interestingly it works just like this if it's not happening in a local plugin. I will open another issue in Gatsbys repo.

Comment: Unfortunately your workaround leads to the same error.